# Duplicate leads to closed as not constructive

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Root: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329254/tomcat-7-vs-jetty
... is marked as a dupe, which leads to:
[Tomcat VS Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302977/tomcat-vs-jetty)
... which is closed a not constructive.

I am confused.  And here I was Googling to compare Tomcat vs. Jetty and find this.

Please kindly explain.

Is there a way this question could be asked in a manner than would satisfy StackOverflow's definition of `constructive`?

Comment: Given that those questions ask for comparisons, advantages/disadvantages, etc. I don't see a way to make this a constructive question that would be allowed on SO, no.

Comment: I fear the answer is no. Any question in the form of "X vs. Y" doesn't fit into Stack Overflow anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Because the comments and answers above aggravate me so much, I reply in-kind with a classic:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your question should be closed as "Not Constructive" too. The problem is that it is impossible to know what priorities and use cases you have for the system.